# Isn't it redundant to dispose of an object inside its own using block?

Tags: c#

While programming over an existent class, I've noticed that someone has written something like this:

```
using(DisposableObject disp = new DisposableObject())
{
    ...
    ...

    disp.Dispose()
}
```

And then I wonder: isn't the using block enough to dispose an object? Could be there any way Dispose() can be useful in such case?

Cause it doesn't make any sense to me...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your case it is useless to use `dispose` inside `using` because when `using` statement's scope ends it automatically calls `dispose`. That's why you can only write objects which implements `IDisposable` Interface inside `using` brackets.

```
using(.......)
```

Moreover if there was any statement using `disp` object after `disp.Dispose()` it would give an error, because by then object would have been disposed, i.e. its memory has been released.

**But beware**

If `dispose` is last line before `using` scope ends then it is useless.

But it is not useless when there are more lines after `dispose`.

Comment: That's what I thought... I guess I should tell someone about this in here

Answer (score 3):

Yes, a using block is actually equivalent to and an alternative syntax for:

```
var d = new DisposableObject();
try
{
    d.DoSomething();
}
finally
{
    if(d != null)
         ((IDisposable)d).Dispose();
}
```

Note that it uses finally instead of something like 'catch'. The finally-clause will always be executed, even if there's an exception.

Answer (score 0):

`using` is enough. There is no reason to call `Dispose` twice.

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons why you can use Dispose inside a using block:

- you want to dispose the object before the using block ends. In this case the using block is a "safety net" that ensures you that your object will be disposed even if an exception happens. (using behaves like a try block which has a finally block in which your object is disposed)
- calling `Dispose` makes more clear what you're doing. This is typical, i.e. of

transaction scopes:

```
using(TransactionScope ts=new TransactionScope)
{
  ...
  if (cond)
  {
    ts.Complete();
  }
  else
  {
    ts.Dispose(); // makes it clear you're rolling back the transaction
  }
}
```

This call to `Dispose` it's not neccesary, but it's "explanatory". It makes more obvous that the transaction is rolled back.

Answer (score 0):

@Nikhil Agrawal is right. One thing I need mention is when you implement Idisposable interface, you should make sure it can be invoked many times. That's mean you should do some validation.