# Disposing Objects Multiple Times

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dispose, using

I am a developer that is maintaining and constantly making an application faster and better. I came across a piece of code that uses `.Dispose()`, which is inside a `using` statement.

**Here is the code:**

```
using (IDbCommand cmd = proxy.Connection.CreateCommand())
{
   cmd.CommandText = "usp_GetPluginInfo";
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   cmd.Parameters.Add(proxy.Connection.CreateParameter(cmd, "@dealershipId", dealershipId));
   cmd.Parameters.Add(proxy.Connection.CreateParameter(cmd, "@pluginId", pluginId));
   PluginInfo[] pluginInfos = PopulatePluginsFromCommand(cmd);
   result = pluginInfos.First();
   cmd.Dispose();
}
```

Wouldn't the last `}` Dispose when the Command is finished?  I didn't think that it was necessary to use `Dispose()` in this case.

Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: Duplicate question: [Isn't it redundant to dispose of an object inside its own using block?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10683086/isnt-it-redundant-to-dispose-of-an-object-inside-its-own-using-block)

Answer (score 6):

You're right, it's not necessary.
A `using` statement is translated by the compiler to this:

```
IDbCommand cmd = proxy.Connection.CreateCommand();

try
{    
    //...
}
finally
{
    if(cmd != null)
        ((IDisposable)cmd).Dispose();
}
```

Having said that, calling `Dispose` more than once *should not* be "hurtful" either, as a proper IDisposable implementation is supposed to be idempotent. It is, however, redundant, and you should remove it, since you're cleaning up the code.

Comment: Almost correct, the assignment is outside the try though. If the assignment throws an exception there is no reason to dispose.

Comment: @EkoostikMartin I've fixed that already :P I also added the explicit cast to `IDisposable`, in case `IDbCommand` implements `Dispose` explicitly.

Comment: Take care to consider `"a proper IDisposable implementation"` though.  Improper implementations may have a problem disposing of a disposed resource.

Comment: @Servy that's true, you shouldn't assume that someone else's implementation adheres to the standards. I changed my sentence to say "shouldn't be hurtful" instead of "isn't hurtful".

Answer (score 1):

You are correct! The `using` block is syntactic sugar for the following:

```
IDbCommand cmd = proxy.Connection.CreateCommand();
try
{
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   cmd.Parameters.Add(proxy.Connection.CreateParameter(cmd, "@dealershipId", dealershipId));
   cmd.Parameters.Add(proxy.Connection.CreateParameter(cmd, "@pluginId", pluginId));
   PluginInfo[] pluginInfos = PopulatePluginsFromCommand(cmd);
   result = pluginInfos.First();}
finally
{
    if(cmd != null)
    {
        ((IDisposable)cmd).Dispose();
    }
}
```

So yes, the extra `cmd.Dispose();` is unnecessary. In most cases, a well-written class will do nothing the second `.Dispose()` (using the so-called [Disposable Pattern](http://geekswithblogs.net/robp/archive/2008/02/03/looking-at-.net-the-disposable-pattern.aspx)), but sometimes it will cause issues. Get rid of it!

Answer (score 0):

`using` statement always calls `IDisposable.Dispose()` method. `cmb.Dispose()` code is redundant

Answer (score 0):

using calls Dispose upon exit of the block, no matter whether the block is run successfully or an exception occurs. In your example, the explicit call to Dispose is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

There is **one** reason he could've put it there explicitly. If the `IDbCommand` isn't the one from `System.Data`, and the interface that was made for some reason inherited from `IDisposable` but used `new` instead of `override`, they could have different behaviours. But it's 99.999999999% of the time absolutely redundant.

Comment: @Turp I know, I was being theoretical.

Answer (score 0):

It's redundant and the explicit call to `Dispose` is not guaranteed to execute. If you want to call `Dispose` explicitly make sure to do it in a finally block.

Answer (score 0):

The cmd.Dispose(); is unnecessary. In a case where Dispose() is not properly implemented or made to throw the System.ObjectDisposedException, this could be an issue

Refer to the code analysis rule below
[The call to CA2202: Do not dispose objects multiple times](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182334.aspx)